# microdnf shows librhsm-WARNING Found 0 entitlement certificates

Tags: docker, rhel, docker-image

**Problem**

I am trying to install nmap-ncat package into a container created with [this image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/percona-xtrabackup/percona/percona-xtrabackup/8.0/images/sha256-bbe9b9378c3fb767cea056353654d594610e65d1d871085b2b0c4ccb20012cb5?context=explore) by microdnf pkg-manager. I run

```
microdnf update
microdnf -y install nmap-ncat
```

Both cmds output

```
(microdnf:xxx): librhsm-WARNING **: 12:00:00.000: Found 0 entitlement certificates

...
```

but both cmds seem to be working properly after this. I can actually see ncat cmd's help by `--help` option so it seems the install is complete.
I googled about this issue and found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/886636/rhel7-atomic-docker-base-image-subscription). It seems since I am not a red hat subscriber, Red Hat Enterprise Linux(RHEL) which is the OS used by [the image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/percona-xtrabackup/percona/percona-xtrabackup/8.0/images/sha256-bbe9b9378c3fb767cea056353654d594610e65d1d871085b2b0c4ccb20012cb5?context=explore) limits what I can do. Maybe the base image of [the image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/percona-xtrabackup/percona/percona-xtrabackup/8.0/images/sha256-bbe9b9378c3fb767cea056353654d594610e65d1d871085b2b0c4ccb20012cb5?context=explore) is one of red hat universal base images (ubi) by which

> allow commercial and open source developers to build containers based on RHEL without requiring them or their users to be RHEL subscribers

[(source)](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/03/24/red-hat-universal-base-images-for-docker-users#) because the output of `microdnf -y install nmap-ncat` is like

```
Installing: ... ;ubi-8-baseos
Installing: ... ;ubi-8-appstream
```

and [this](https://access.redhat.com/articles/4238681) shows both ubi-8-baseos and ubi-8-appstream are RHEL 8 UBI repositories (but I am not really sure about this).
My questions are

1. Why did the warning come up while I successfully installed nmap-ncat?
2. Am I entitled to use nmap-ncat with [this image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/percona-xtrabackup/percona/percona-xtrabackup/8.0/images/sha256-bbe9b9378c3fb767cea056353654d594610e65d1d871085b2b0c4ccb20012cb5?context=explore)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore the warning: just like running regular `dnf`, `microdnf` is configured to work with Red Hat subscriptions. If you have entitlements on your host, they will be automatically mounted into the container, giving you access to subscription-only resources.

If you don't have entitlements, you'll see the warning, but you can ignore it.

> Am I entitled to use nmap-ncat with this image?

You will not be able to install software to which you do not have an entitlement, so if you can install it, you're fine.

Comment: with `dnf` you can silence the warnings by removing `subscription-manager`. but with `microdnf` there does not appear to be a way to silence the warnings (i tried `rpm -e --nodeps librhsm && microdnf install -y gcc` and removing librhsm breaks `microdnf`).